# Animating UIView with auto layout when the view is just created and about to appear

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` that contains subviews that contains subviews...(Hierarchy of `UIViews`).

Every `UIView` is set with auto layout. When I press a button, this `UIView` is created and then I would like it to drop from the top of the screen.

The problem when I use `layoutIfNeeded` in an animation is that if will animate everything at the same time as it is a newly created `UIView` (not yet display).

My question is, is there a way to do the animation of only the `UIView` dropping with all the subviews already laid out in it?

I guess you can do it by creating the `UIView` when `UIViewController` displays and then hide it but I was wondering it there was another way.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you call `layoutIfNeeded` right after you add it to a view, while still outside the view, it should lay out it's views correctly. And then in the animation you call it again so the view animate to the final position.